# Permissions to be granted to developers to investigate jobs, queries, and packages

Tags: permissions, ssis, jobs, system-tables, system-databases

I have just installed a new sql server 2014 server, migrated some databases there and connected some applications to them.

These servers have also SSAS and SSIS.

I have a group of developers there were helping with the connections and doing all the last developments on packages, and data warehousing stuff.

Now that everything is working, I want to remove the sysadmin permissions that I had previously granted them.

Now, these guys they have some requirements,

that I am willing to grant them, so that it is less weight on my shoulders:

> 1) They need to see query plans, 2) they need to identify missing
>   indexes and other expensive operations like key lookups, etc
>
> 3) they need to query sys views and tables - monitor what procedures
>   are running, collect WAIT STATS, etc
>
> 4) they also need to troubleshoot JOBS - so they need to be able to
>   see them, see the job history, in order to find out what went wrong
>
> 5) they also need to see everything in the SSIS integration catalog,
>   so that when something goes wrong inside one of there packages they
>   are able to figure it out by themselves

I have granted them with the following **SERVER permissions**:

> 1) view server state
>
> 2) view any definition

on the **MSDB database**:

I got some ideas from "[SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx)"

[image]

and finally on the **SSISDB database**

[image]

Anything else that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't grant ssis_admin if the dev shouldn't be sysadmins:

> Members of the db_ssisadmin role and the dc_admin role may be able to elevate their privileges to sysadmin.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141053.aspx

Personally I would never let the devs create jobs with their accounts. As soon as they leave the company and someone disables the AD account, all their jobs stop working...

Btw: don't grant server rights directly but with a serverrole.